# check aria2 download progress by program

Tags: aria2

I have a script that crawls a torrent site and download them automatically. 
Certain torrent takes forever to download for lack of seeding. 
How can i programatically detect such situation and 
`pkill aria2c`

Comment: Use the [rpc-interface](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#rpc-interface)